How to add columns and insert data in Common Lisp ltk treeview
am trying to create a table using a scrolled-treeview, to contain students' performance but i have failed to add the specific columns (name, math-mark, comp-mark) to it.
I have tried the following code but it returns an error
;; test.lisp
(ql:quickload :ltk)
(in-package :ltk)

(with-ltk ()
    (let* ((tree (make-instance 'scrolled-treeview :columns '(0 1 2)) ))
        ; Adding the heading to the column
        (treeview-heading tree 0 "Name") 
        (treeview-heading tree 1 "Math")
        (treeview-heading tree 2 "COMP")
        ; Adding record to the created table.
        (treeview-insert tree :values '("Simon Due" "78" "60"))
        (treeview-insert tree :values '("Kato Ronald" "80" "90"))

        (pack tree)
    )  
)

i expected to return a scrolled-treeview with the two records.
Below is the error i get when load test.lisp
Invalid initializattion argument: :columns
in call for class #<STANDARD-CLASS LTK:SCROLLED-TREEVIEW>


I couldn't find an example with Ltk, but I have one with nodgui.
It appears however than while Ltk has a scrolled treeview, it doesn't support the :columns argument.
The API is:
(make-instance 'scrolled-treeview
               :columns (list "col1" "col2"))

then
(treeview-insert-item tree :text "text" :column-values (list "other" "columns"))

see:

nodgui demos
my Ltk and nodgui tests (search scrolled-treeview)

Dev note: I found it simpler to wrap the GUI code in a function, because we can compile the function and get errors and warnings, without running the Tk window and getting an error.
This gives us a simple scrolled treeview:
#++
(ql:quickload :nodgui)

(in-package :nodgui)

(defun run ()
 (with-nodgui ()
    (let* ((tree (make-instance 'scrolled-treeview :columns '("col1" "col2")) ))
      (treeview-insert-item tree :text "one" :column-values (list "two" "three"))
      (pack tree))))

buuuut this creates a table with 3 columns and "col1" is the name of the second one. I'd have to sort this out. I think I got this right in one of my examples. Or, no I didn't, I assumed a treeview always has one column, and I didn't find how to name it.

Thank you Ehvince, but i had tried-out this particular approach and i realized  i had to change the code incredibly.(had to make a lot of changes)

This did the work for me.

(ql:quickload :ltk)
(in-package :ltk) 

(with-ltk ()
          (wm-title *tk* "test.lisp")
          (let* ((tree (make-instance 'scrolled-treeview)))

          ;specifies the columns by index(integer) !! not string
          (configure (treeview tree) :columns '(0 1))

          ;specifies the table heading.
          (treeview-heading (treeview tree) "#0" :text "Name" ) ;specifies the initial column of the table
          (treeview-heading (treeview tree) 0 :text "Math")
          (treeview-heading (treeview tree) 1 :text "COMP")

          ;inserts records into the table....
          (treeview-insert (treeview tree) :text '(Kato Samuel) :values (list "89" "80" )) ;this works
          (treeview-insert (treeview tree) :text '(Mary Thereza) :values '("85" "90" )) ;these works too
          (treeview-insert (treeview tree) :text '(Opio Denis) :values '("70" "80" ))

          (grid tree 1 0)
          )
)

However, when it  comes to the initial column of the treeview it's "#0" and not 0 as indicated in the configure.
